# AngularJS ng-repeat and video's ng-src

Tags: angularjs

I have a basic `ng-repeat` loop that displays my content but if I use `ng-src` for video tags it causes this error:

```
Error: [$interpolate:noconcat] Error while interpolating: http://localhost{{post.media}}
```

I know I can use a `$sce` service but I am not sure how to utilize it in the context of `ng-repeat`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `ngRepeat`. It is Angular's SCE protecting you from a potentially unsafe practice.

1.) You could create a function in your controller that generates the URL:

```
var host = 'http://localhost/';
$scope.generateURL = function (media) {
    return host + media;
};
```

2.) Then, call it from the view:

```
... ng-src="{{generateURL(post.media)}}"
```

---

Take a look at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302909/how-is-concatenating-urls-in-templates-in-angular-less-secure-than-in-other-loca/23740248#23740248)** for more info on why the error occurs and what is `SCE`'s purpose.