# Angular String interpolation in attribute template

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-template

What is the best practice for string interpolation in attribute in Angular 6?

I have this code:

`<div class="container" [ngStyle]="{'grid-template-rows': 'repeat(' + value + ', 1fr) [last-line]'}">`

I want to use something like  `'repeat(${value})'` with backtick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can move the functionality to your component and use backticks there:

```
calculateStyle(value: string): string {
   return `repeat(${value}, 1fr) [last-line]`;
}
```

and in template:

`<div class="container" [ngStyle]="{'grid-template-rows': calculateStyle(value)}">`

However you should try to avoid calling function from template whenever possible, so consider using some technique to avoid that (e.g. having observable remapped from an input, using state management, ...)

Comment: mmm it's not good solution for me. I think that this logic must is put in template and not have a custom function.

Comment: why *must*  you put logic in the template? moving code from template to component brings several benefits. if you don't like calling function on each render cycle, then you might recalculate the style whenewer value changes and store it in  component property and use that property.

Comment: Why You Should Never Use Methods Inside Templates in Angular - https://betterprogramming.pub/why-you-should-never-use-methods-inside-templates-in-angular-497e0e11f948

Comment: If your view is based on your model and you model changes because of a method, this is just must better than calling a method, and probably get the same output as you did 5 seconds ago. MVC or MVX has this flow for a reason

Comment: `never` is too strong IMO ;), however i agree that it is a good practice to avoid calling function directly whenever possible, that's why i added the part about that.

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for answer to the question, and while Mauricio expresses opinion based on article about using methods in templates, I think this is fine on a case-by-case basis. Hence, my upvote on the original answer.

However, I would like to build a string from logic in the template - like the question states.  In my test on ver 14+, concatenating is possible with the double braces.  For example:

```
<someComponent
  someProperty="{{someObj?.anotherProp}}{{someVar ? ' [TEST]' : null}}">
</someComponent>
```

Note the omission of the square brackets on the property name.

Comment: Feel free to check this other discussion - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302909/how-is-concatenating-urls-in-templates-in-angular-less-secure-than-in-other-loca

Comment: also the article, as far as I remember show pretty clear how to measure how many times your method in the template is being called, so the is not opinion based, it should be used carefully